# How to update file in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $request->validate([        
        'customername' =>'required',
        'mobilenumber' =>'required',
        'alternatemobilenumber' => ' nullable',
        'email' => ' nullable',
        'temporaryaddress1' => ' nullable',
        'temporaryaddress2' => ' nullable',
        'temporaryaddress3' => ' nullable',
        'temporarypincode' => ' nullable',
        'permanantaddress1' => 'required',
        'permanantaddress2' => 'required',
        'permanantaddress3' => 'required',
        'permanantpincode' => 'required',
        'idproof' => 'required',
        'proofnumber' => 'required',
        'prooffile' => 'required|file|mimes:pdf,xlsx,docx,csv|max:2048'
    ]);
    $update = ['prooffile' => $request->prooffile];
    if ($files = $request->file('prooffile')) {
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/userfiles';
        $prooffile =  $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $update['prooffile'] = $prooffile;
        $files->move($destinationPath, $prooffile);
    }
    $update['prooffile'] = $request->file('prooffile');
    $customer=customer::where('id',$id)->update($update);
    $request->prooffile = $prooffile ;
```

I want to update the file in the user file folder in public_path(). I tried with update() it only updates the path where the file saves like C:\Users\User\xammp server\tmp\php847C.tmp. I wish to   update the old file  and  instead of saving the path in the table I want to save the name of the file in the database.

Comment: $image = $request->file('prooffile');
        $name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . str_replace(' ', '-', $image->getClientOriginalName());
        $image->move(public_path('/' . $store_path), $name);
        
        $update['prooffile'] = $store_path . '/' . $name;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $customer = customer::find($id);
    if ($request->hasFile('prooffile')) {
        $image = $request->file('prooffile');
        $store_path = "upload/Profile_pic";
        $name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true)) . str_replace(' ', '-', $image->getClientOriginalName());
        $image->move(public_path('/' . $store_path), $name);
        $exist_image = $customer['prooffile'];
        $update['prooffile'] = $store_path . '/' . $name;
    }
    $customer->update($update);
```

just create one folder in **public folder => upload** and then inside create another folder according to your need.

and delete the old file if exist in a public folder like this, **added this after the update successfully.**

```
       if (isset($exist_image) && file_exists($exist_image)) {
            unlink($exist_image);
        }
```

Comment: first, update the new file and then unlink old file, if you unlink first old file then if any issue in updating the new file then it creates a problem. so always unlink old file in last.

Answer (score 1):

First find customer by id.

If user found then  upload new image to folder and also make sure random name generated for filename doesn't exist already in db.

Next upload image to folder and delete already uploaded image from server.

Next Update to db.
Here is the small code .Here uploaded images are stored in path called `storage/app/public/images`  to retrieve images you have to create symbolic link using following command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This will create shortcut folder in `public/` folder. While retrieving url look like this `http://urdomain/storage/images/filename.extension`

```
$customer=customer::find($id);
 
 if($customer){
 
    if ($request->hasFile('prooffile')) {
        
     $fileName = str_random(5).'_'. round(microtime(true) * 1000) . '.' . $request->prooffile->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $request->file('prooffile')->storeAs('images', $fileName, 'public');
     $update['prooffile'] = $prooffile;
     Storage::disk('public')->delete('images/'.$customer->prooffile);
                  
    }
                
    $customer->update($update)
    
}
```

Comment: $request->file('prooffile')->storeAs('images', $customer->prooffile, 'public');